# Where can we ask normal software questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I try to play a 3D Blu-ray on windows 10 but I am not able to with my software. Where is the correct place to ask such normal basic questions?

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/), assuming that you can provide enough detail to make it answerable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In its current state I doubt that question is very useful anywhere within the network.

If you improve it by adding much more details it might fly on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as their help center says:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer software,

but that assumes the issue is related to drivers or your software settings because it kind of rules out ...

> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

Before you post make sure to add:

- name, brand, version of your Blu-Ray player
- Software version you use
- drivers installed, including version and manufacturer
- what exactly *not able to play* means
- Exact Windows version
- Any attempts to resolve the issue
- whether hardware failure is already ruled out

and don't stop there.